# Stitching a full spherical mosaic using only a smartphone and sensor data?

Tags: computer-vision, image-stitching

I'm really interested in the Google Street View mobile application, which integrates a method to create a fully functional spherical panorama using only your smartphone camera. (Here's the procedure for anyone interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPs3eIiWRaw)

What strikes me the most is that it always manages to create the full sphere, even when stitching a feature-less near monochrome blue sky or ceiling ; which gets me to thinking that they're not using feature based matching.

Is it possible to get a decent quality full spherical mosaic without using feature based matching and only using sensor data? Are smartphone sensors precise enough? What library would be usable to do this? OpenCV? Something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The features are needed for registration. In the app the clever UI makes sure they already know where each photo is relative to the sphere so in the extreme case all the have to do is reproject/warp and blend. No additional geometry processing needed.

I would assume that they do try to do some small corrections to improve the registration, but even if these fail, you can fallback onto the sensor based ones acquired at capture time.

This is a case where a clever UI makes the vision problem significantly easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "the clever UI makes sure they already know where each photo is relative to the sphere", you do mean they know the image pairing right? 
Can it give any other information besides pairing?